# Using GCP Data Transfer Service to transfer files from S3 previously stored in glacier

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-data-transfer

Was using the GCP data transfer service to transfer a set of files in an S3 bucket over to a GCP storage bucket.  The files were in glacier so I first restored them and then tried copying them. The transfer job runs without any errors, but ignores any of the glacier restored files.  Is this the expected behavior?  And if it is then it seems like a huge oversight not to mention this in the documentation.  I could easily imagine a scenario where you *think* you've mirrored a bucket when you really haven't.